# How does Learning a Spell work with repertoires?

Tags: spellcasting, pathfinder-2e

How does Learn a Spell work with repertoires? For example, my primal sorcerer obtained spell scrolls of *heal* and *fear*, neither of which were in their repertoire. From my understanding, I roll a DC 15 Nature skill check, spend 2 gp per spell, and 1 hour per level of the spell learned.

What happens next? From what I understand, these new spells would become available as spell choices once the sorcerer went up a level. There's no immediate advantage to adding spells to the repertoire (unlike a wizard's spellbook), but it expands available spell choices as the repertoire caster becomes more powerful.

For reference:
Learn a Spell: https://2e.aonprd.com/Skills.aspx?ID=4&General=true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, however, you can also take the downtime activity 'retrain' to change your current selection of spells.

While there are not rules specifically for swapping spells, there are rules for swapping class features, and spells are a class feature - roughly 30 days of downtime would let you change all your spells. If you only want to change one spell, I suggest talking to your DM about reducing the amount of time required.

Also, though I don't know of one for a Primal Sorcerer, there are feats for some kinds of Sorcerer and Bard that make swapping spells much easier (e.g. Arcane Evolution for Arcane Sorcerer).

Comment: This is a more complete answer, I hadn't considered downtime activities. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding and assessment is correct. 'Learning a spell' simply makes the spell available to you. By itself this does nothing for a repertoire caster, but can be selected when you level up.